# IIS Express timestamp in log files one hour behind

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

Anyone experienced the IIS Express timestamp in log files being one hour behind the actual time?

Comment: is it maybe logging in UTC and you're one hour ahead of that? (or your server time and timezone settings are not set up properly?)

Comment: Ignoring Daylight Savings time???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express (and also IIS) timestamps are in UTC.